# morpher app soundboard does not contain a valid Info.plist so it cannot be installed on Jared iPhone CFBundleExecutable isn't specified. What do I do?

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, swift3, xcode8

This happens when I try to run the app on my phone. here is the error

“morpher app soundboard” does not contain a valid Info.plist, so it cannot be installed on Jared's iPhone
(“CFBundleExecutable” is not specified)
How do I fix this error?

here is the code
from the viewController.swift file

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{

let soundFilenames = ["5","8","7","4","6","1","3","2"]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()
var lastAudioPlayer = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Set up audio players
    for sound in soundFilenames {

        do {

            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")!)
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOf:url)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
        }
        catch {

                       audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())
        }
               }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0;
    audioPlayer.play();
}
@IBAction func button(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped

    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    let audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0;
    audioPlayer.play()

}

}
}
```

and here is the code from the appDelegate.swift file

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  //Error happens on this line... Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

and also if you were wondering...

[here is the plist file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBANZ.png)

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: just added it. how do fix the error, “morpher app soundboard” does not contain a valid Info.plist, so it cannot be installed on Jared's iPhone
(“CFBundleExecutable” is not specified)

Comment: ?...///???...??

Comment: it is at the top part of post

Comment: CAN YOU HELP ME EFIX THE ERROR\

Comment: fix I meant to say

Comment: how do I specify CFBundleExecutable because I get this error (“CFBundleExecutable” is not specified)

Comment: now I get this error error: couldn't parse contents of '/Users/jaredmiller1/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/.Trash/app soundboard 2/morpher app soundboard/Info.plist': The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.